# Image zooming Ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, zooming

I’m trying to build a slider with ion-slides where I want the user to be able to pinch to zoom.

I have tried hard coding it but zooming isn’t smooth and I feel like there is much better ways to do it natively.
any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding div with swiper-zoom-container class?

```
<ion-slides pager="true" style="height:45%" zoom>
<ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of selProd.productImages">
  <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
    <img src="{{slide.image}}">
  </div>
</ion-slide>
```

Comment: I can only zoom to the center of the image and the image zooms out as soon as I stop pinching

Comment: And cannot pan the image after zooming.